# Can't get elements from SOAPHeader correctly

Tags: java, soap, java-web-start

So I have this SOAP Message:

```
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:SOAP-ENV=" http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<SOAP-ENV:Header>
<pid:pid   xmlns:pid="pt:ulisboa:tecnico:sdis:store:ws">carla</pid:pid>  </SOAP-ENV:Header> <S:Body><ns2:
loadResponse xmlns:ns2="urn:pt:ulisboa:tecnico:sdis:store:ws"/></S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

So you see pid="carla"

But when I get all the attributes:

```
Iterator iter = hd.extractAllHeaderElements();
while(iter.hasNext()){
   System.out.println(iter.next());
}
```

All it prints is:

```
[pid:pid: null]
```

Any ideas why it isn't "carla"?

I'm doing all this processing in the handlers.